# Not getting my expectation result in Join Query for multiple conditions using C# mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, lambda

I am trying to compare the two collections in MongoDB C# for so many times but I am not getting the expectation result.
Here is my code.

**UserDetails Collection**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("585bc1b137bd32466cfe1472"),
"NTID" : "kram",
"FirstName" : "KRamesh"
```

}

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("585bc1b137bd32466cfe1473"),
"NTID" : "raj",
"FirstName" : "Rajan"
```

}

**ReportDetails Collection**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59d347c77ab9655380bdb452"),
"FaxID" : "123",
"CreatedBy" : "kram",
"CreatedDate" : ISODate("2017-10-03T08:14:18.323Z"),
"LastModifiedBy" : "kram",
"LastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-02-01T10:25:14.719Z")
```

}

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59d347c77ab9655380bdb453"),
"FaxID" : "124",
"CreatedBy" : "raj",
"CreatedDate" : ISODate("2017-10-03T08:14:18.323Z"),
"LastModifiedBy" : "kram",
"LastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-02-01T10:25:14.719Z")
```

}

```
BsonResult = Collection.Find(finalQuery).OrderByDescending(c => c[_SortBy]).Skip(Skip).Take(Take).ToList();

                        var details = (from report in BsonResult.AsQueryable()
                                       join user in CollectionUserDetails.AsQueryable()
                                          on report["CreatedBy"] equals user["NTID"]
                                          into joinedreport
                        select new
                        {  
                            joinedreportings = joinedreport
                        }).ToList();
```

> My Expectation Result look like

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59d347c77ab9655380bdb452"),
"FaxID" : "123",
"CreatedBy" : "KRamesh",
"CreatedDate" : ISODate("2017-10-03T08:14:18.323Z"),
"LastModifiedBy" : "KRamesh",
"LastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-02-01T10:25:14.719Z")
```

}

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59d347c77ab9655380bdb453"),
"FaxID" : "124",
"CreatedBy" : "Rajan",
"CreatedDate" : ISODate("2017-10-03T08:14:18.323Z"),
"LastModifiedBy" : "KRamesh",
"LastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-02-01T10:25:14.719Z")
```

}

> Please give me the solution..

Thanks,
Pari

Comment: It may be helpful to **highlight** the differences between what you received and what you expected.

Comment: I want to compare the **createdBy** field and **ModifiedBy** field in **ReportDetails** Collection to **NTID** Field in UserDetails, If it is Same as then show the **FirstName** Field in UserDetails collection.